# Existence of a nonsingular submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

**Why is the following true?**

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ with rank $r \le \min(n,m)$, there are row and column sets
$$
\{ i_1, \ldots, i_r \}, \quad
\{ j_1, \ldots, j_r \},
$$
such that the $r\times r$ submatrix
$$
(\hat A_{s,t})_{s,t=1}^r = A_{i_s,j_t}
$$
is nonsingular.

---

Of course, with the column rank of $A$ being $r$, we can find $r$ linearly independent columns of $A$. But how can we know that they stay linearly independent after restricting them to the $r$ similarly chosen rows of $A$?

Comment: After some more searching, an elementary proof seems to have been stated here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/368428/164698

Answer (score 1):

Because the corresponding $r\times r$ minor is non-zero.

Comment: That's just restating the question using different words. Why is the minor nonzero?

Comment: An $n\times r$ matrix has rank $r$ if and only if some $r$ minor of this matrix is no-zero. The corresponding rows and columns are linearly independent.

Comment: But the matrix is not $n \times r$, it is $n \times m$, where $m$ may be greater than $r$.

Comment: I was speaking of the submatrix corresponding to the $r$ independent columns.