# Submatrix formed from independent rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose matrix A has rank r. Pick any r independent rows and r independent columns from A. Must the submatrix formed from these rows and columns be invertible?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: @Shailesh I think i'ts invertible but I can't prove it.

Comment: Just found this question was asked:  (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368408/an-r-times-r-submatrix-of-independent-rows-and-independent-columns-is-invertib?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

- $\,A\,$ be an $\,m{\,\times\,}n\,$ matrix of rank $r$.$\\[3pt]$

  $\,R\,$ be an $\,r{\,\times\,}\,n$ submatrix of $A$ with $r$ linearly independent rows.$\\[3pt]$

  $\,C\,$ be an $\,m{\,\times\,}r\,$ submatrix of $A$ with $r$ linearly independent columns.$\\[3pt]$

  $\,B\,$ be the $\,r{\,\times\,}r\,$ submatrix of $A$ formed by intersecting the rows of $R$ with the columns of $C$.

Claim $B$ is invertible.

Since $B$ is a submatrix of $A$,  $\text{rank}(B) \le r$.

By construction, $R$ has rank $r$, as does $C$.

If row $i$ of A is not one of the rows from $R$, then it must be linearly dependent on the rows from $R$, hence row $i$ of $C$ is linearly dependent on those rows from $C$ which are in $B$.

It follows that $\text{rank}(C) \le \text{rank}(B)$, hence $r \le \text{rank}(B)$.

Thus, $r \le \text{rank}(B) \le r$, so $\text{rank}(B) = r$.

It follows that $B$ is invertible, as claimed.

Comment: Nice proof. Thank you.