# For a non-null matrix A, show that a submatrix of A formed by k linearly independent rows and k linearly independent columns need not be invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a non-null matrix $A_{m \times n}$, show that a submatrix of A formed by $k$ linearly independent rows and $k$ linearly independent columns need not be invertible.

According to me, it should be always invertible.  The Gauss Jordan elimination method of finding inverse is premised upon it. How it can be disproved?

Comment: What is $k$? If $A\in M_n(K)$, do we have $k=n$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $k \leq \min(m, n)$ where the order of the matrix if $m \times 
 n$.

Comment: Ah, I see. You should edit your post and say that $A\in M_{m,n}(K)$ and for all $k\le\min (m,n)$.

Comment: If $k=r$ is the rank of $A$, then see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184360/submatrix-formed-from-independent-rows-and-columns). For other $k$ this need not be true.

Comment: My question is different. In the question, you mentioned it was asked to prove that the submatrix will be invertible. In my textbook, it was asked to prove that not always invertible.

Comment: Exactly. For $k=r$ it is always invertible, but in your case, not always, because for that we would need that $k=r$ in general, where $r$ is the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss-Jordan elimination only uses invertibility in the special case when $k$ is equal to the rank of $A$.  If $k$ is smaller than the rank, the submatrix can fail to be invertible.

For a simple example, let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.  Then the first row of $A$ is linearly independent, as is the first column.  However, their intersection is just $\begin{pmatrix} 0\end{pmatrix}$ which is not invertible.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking directly in terms of matrices. I didn't think about including a vector.